# Events in java web app. When to use

Tags: java, spring, email, events, notifications

Currently I'm thinking on the case:
We have `UserService` with `registerUser()` method.
After successfully registration of a new user we should send them email notification. We have `EmailService` for sending.

What is better approach here, inject `EmailService` into `UserService` and declare `onRegistrationSucces()` method in `UserService`

OR

fire an event `RegistrationSuccesEvent` and provide `Listener`, which would operate with `EmailService`?

Is there some pros of using events int such case?

Comment: This is two question in one. Please split into separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Decoupling trough Listeners makes sense, if the sender can not or should not know about the receiver or you often need to add new listeners. But like always you pay a price for that, it can make the application more difficult to implement,understand or debug.

In your case I would just autowire it.
If you later have to add a SMS service or other receivers, you can still change the implementation to listeners if you want.